# Как в переменную записать символы "(", ")"?

Tags: linux, bash, .bashrc

Нужно написать программу, которая принимает на вход любое количество символов: "**(**", "**)**" и выводить **true** - если все скобки закрыты, иначе выводит **false**.
Проблема находится в самих скобках. Если на ввод просто ввести: **()**. То выведется ошибка: "bash: синтаксическая ошибка рядом с неожиданным маркером «(»". Но если, ввести вот так: **\(\)**, то программа считает их символами.
Вопрос, что нужно сделать, чтобы скрипт получал на вход просто скобки без слэшей ("**()**") и считал их символами?

Дополнение вопрос:
Если ввожу sh script.sh (), выводится ошибка. Но если так sh script.sh \(\), то программа работает. Но нужно чтобы скрипт воспринимал первый вариант

```
Skobki_t_f ()
{
skobki=$1
echo $skobki | cut -b 1
}
 
Skobki_t_f $1
exit 0
```

Comment: `"()"` или `'()'`

Comment: Я эти кавычки поставил просто для большего понимания вопроса, в коде они не учавствуют

Comment: Если ввожу sh script.sh (), выводится ошибка. Но если так sh script.sh \\(\\), то программа работает. Но нужно чтобы скрипт воспринимал первый вариант

Comment: `$ sh script "()"` или `$ sh script '()'`

Comment: А, я понял что имеется ввиду. При вводе $ sh script "()" или $ sh script '()'. все работает. Но задам уточняющий вопрос. Можно ли как-то другим способом ввести входные данные в строку из консоли?

Comment: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html